# Learning the High Order Perl: issue with iterator

Tags: perl

I study the High Order Perl book and have an issue with iterators in the Chapter 4.3.4.

The code:

main_script.pl

```
#!/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib $Bin;
use Iterator_Utils qw(:all);
use FlatDB;

my $db = FlatDB->new("$Bin/db.csv") or die "$!";
my $q = $db->query('STATE', 'NY');
while (my $rec = NEXTVAL($q) )
{
     print $rec;
}
```

Iterator_Utils.pm

```
#!/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
package Iterator_Utils;
use Exporter 'import';;
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(NEXTVAL Iterator
            append imap igrep
            iterate_function filehandle_iterator list_iterator);
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ('all' => \@EXPORT_OK);
sub NEXTVAL { $_[0]->() }
sub Iterator (&) { return $_[0] }
```

FlatDB.pm

```
#!/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package FlatDB;

my $FIELDSEP = qr/:/;

sub new 
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $file = shift;

    open my $fh, "<", $file or return;
    chomp(my $schema = <$fh>);

    my @field = split $FIELDSEP, $schema;
    my %fieldnum = map { uc $field[$_] => $_ } (0..$#field);
   bless 
   { 
       FH => $fh, 
       FIELDS => \@field, 
       FIELDNUM => \%fieldnum,
       FIELDSEP => $FIELDSEP 
   } => $class;
}

use Fcntl ':seek';
sub query 
{
     my $self = shift;
     my ($field, $value) = @_;
     my $fieldnum = $self->{FIELDNUM}{uc $field};
     return unless defined $fieldnum;
     my $fh = $self->{FH};
     seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;
     <$fh>; # discard schema line
     return Iterator 
     {
       local $_;
       while (<$fh>) 
       {
            chomp;
            my @fields = split $self->{FIELDSEP}, $_, -1;
            my $fieldval = $fields[$fieldnum];
            return $_ if $fieldval eq $value;
       }
       return;
    };
 }
```

db.csv

```
LASTNAME:FIRSTNAME:CITY:STATE:OWES
Adler:David:New York:NY:157.00
Ashton:Elaine:Boston:MA:0.00
Dominus:Mark:Philadelphia:PA:0.00
Orwant:Jon:Cambridge:MA:26.30
Schwern:Michael:New York:NY:149658.23
Wall:Larry:Mountain View:CA:-372.14
```

Just as in the book so far, right? However I do not get the output (the strings with Adler and Schwern should occur). The error message is:

```
 Can't use string ("Adler:David:New York:NY:157.00") as a subroutine ref while 
"strict refs" in use at N:/Perle/Learn/Iterators/Iterator_Utils.pm line 12, <$fh> 
line 3.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks very much for finding this error. I will add this to [the errata on the web site](http://hop.perl.plover.com/errata/errata-p-2.html). If you would like to be credited by name,  please email me your name.

Comment: [This error is now listed on the errata page](http://hop.perl.plover.com/errata/errata-p-1.html#p140).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`FlatDB` calls `Iterator`, which is defined in `Iterator_Utils`, so it needs to import that function from `Iterator_Utils`.  If you add

```
use Iterator_Utils qw(Iterator);
```

after `package FlatDB`, the program will work.

Thanks very much for finding this error. I will add this to [the errata on the web site](http://hop.perl.plover.com/errata/errata-p-2.html). If you would like to be credited by name,  please email me your name.